# Combining two simple related linq queries

Tags: c#, linq

I have two queries and i'm using the result of the first one in the second one like this

```
 var temp  = (ObjectTable.Where(o => o.Category == "Y"));
 var anonymousObjList = temp.Select(o => new {o, IsMax = (o.Value == temp.Max(x => x.Value))});
```

Is there a way to combine these into one query?

EDIT:
I cannot just chain them directly because I'm using temp.Max() in the second query.

Comment: I don't think there is a way you could turn this into a single query. Also, there probably isn't any reason to do that (The only thing you could do is to add `ToList` at the end of the first one if the loading of data uses some slow `IEnumerable` data source).

Comment: where is Jon Skeet when you need him?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can* do it in one statement using query syntax, using the `let` keyword.  It only evaluates the 'max' once, so it just like the three separate statements, just in one line.

```
var anonymousObjList = from o in ObjectTable
                       where o.Category == "Y"
                       let max = ObjectTable.Max(m => m.Value)
                       select new { o, IsMax = (o.Value == max) };
```

This is the only time I ever use query syntax.  You can't do this using method syntax!

edit: ReSharper suggests

```
var anonymousObjList = ObjectTable.Where(o => o.Category == "Y")
    .Select(o => new {o, max = ObjectTable.Max(m => m.Value)})
    .Select(@t => new {@t.o, IsMax = (@t.o.Value == @t.max)});
```

however this is not optimal.  The first Select is projecting a `max` Property for each item in ObjectTable - the Max function will be evaluated for every item.  If you use query syntax it's only evaluated once.

Again, *you can only do this with query syntax*.  I'm not fan of query syntax but this makes it worthwhile, and is the only case in which I use it.  ReSharper is wrong.

Comment: Awesome!.
I got  `var anonymousObjList = ObjectTable.Where(o => o.Category == "Y").Select(o => new {o, max = ObjectTable.Max(m => m.Value)}).
                    Select(@t => new {@t.o, IsMax = (@t.o.Value == @t.max)});` from resharper's conversion.

Comment: @StackOverflowException - That's not bad but it's still not as efficient as using query syntax.  You are evalating `new { o, max = ObjectTable.Max(m => m.Value) }` for each and every object in `ObjectTable`.  If you use query syntax, it's only evaluated once.

Answer (score 5):

Why? it would be clearer (and more efficient) to make it three:

```
var temp  = (ObjectTable.Where(o => o.Category == "Y"));
int max = temp.Max(x => x.Value);
var anonymousObjList = temp.Select(o => new {o, IsMax = (o.Value == max)});
```

Comment: I don't want to create temp collection.

Comment: I don't see the problem with the temp variable here. Due to deferred execution temp doesn't have any negative performance impact, while evaluating max once instead of once per anonymous object will make it faster.

Comment: +1 - he's right.  This is how something like this would normally be written.  It might be possible to string something together to do what you're asking, but the result would not be more performant, and certainly not more readable than this.

Comment: @StackOverflowException: No temp collection is created.  "temp" is only a query, not the results of the query.  Only once you do something that requires the results (looping through the data, getting the max, etc) is there any actualy work done.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the most straightfirward refactoring is to replace all instances of "temp" with the value of temp.  Since it appears that this value is immutable, the refactoring should be valid (yet ugly):

```
var anonymousObjList = ObjectTable.Where(o => o.Category == "Y")
    .Select(o => new {o, IsMax = (o.Value == ObjectTable.Where(o => o.Category == "Y").Max(x => x.Value))});
```

As has already been pointed out, this query really has no advantages over the original, since queries use deffered execution and can be built up.  I would actually suggest *splitting the query even more*:

```
var temp  = (ObjectTable.Where(o => o.Category == "Y")); 
var maxValue = temp.Max(x => x.Value);    
var anonymousObjList = temp.Select(o => new {o, IsMax = (o.Value == maxValue)});
```

This *is* better than the original because every time "Max" is called causes another iteration over the entire dataset.  Since it is being called in the Select of the original, Max was being called n times.  That makes the original O(n^2)!